# How to add a custom scale factor behind EACH major x tick label?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I managed to customize my scaling factor (axis multiplier) by adding:

```
    scaled x ticks=manual:{$  \cdot 10^{14} $}{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
```

The scaling factor now appears once somewhere under my x axis. Now I want the scaling factor to appear after each single x tick label. Is that possible, or is there another approach for this problem of adding customizable text/math content behind each tick label?

MWE:

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ 
    scaled x ticks=manual:{$  \cdot 10^{14} $}{%
        \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    }
 ]
 \addplot [domain=1:5] {x}; 
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\cdot 10^{14}$}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\cdot 10^{14}$}
  ]
  \addplot [domain=1:5] {x}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```